# If $B$ is the set of condensation points of a set $A$, show that every point of $B$ is a condensation point of $B$.

Tags: metric-spaces, separable-spaces

This problem comes from Dieudonné's *Foundations of Modern Analysis*:

> Let $E$ be a separable metric space. A condensation point $x$ of a subset $A$ of $E$ is a point $x \in E$ such that in every neighborhood of $x$, there is a nondenumerable set of points of $A$. Show that: 
> **(a)** If $A$ has no condensation point, it is denumerable (consider the intersections of $A$ with the sets of a basis for the open sets of $E$).
>
> **(b)** If $B$ is the set of condensation points of a set $A$, show that every point of $B$ is a condensation point of $B$, and that $A \cap (\complement B)$ is at most denumerable. (Observe that $B$ is closed, and use **(a)**.)

I've managed to solve **(a)** in the following way:
Let $x$ be any point of $A$. There exists a neighbourhood $V_x$ of $x$, such that it contains at most $\aleph_0$ elements from $A$ (since $A$ has no condensation points). Since $E$ is separable, there exists a denumerable basis $(G_\lambda)$ for all open sets of $E$, and there exists an element of the basis $G_x$ such that $x \in G_x \subset V$. Now we have $A \subset \bigcup_{x \in A} G_x$. But since every set $G_x$ contains at most $\aleph_0$ elements of $A$ (as it is a subset of $V_x$) and the sum $\bigcup_{x \in A} G_x$ is a sum of at most $\aleph_0$ distinct sets, $\bigcup_{x \in A} G_x$ contains itself at most $\aleph_0$ elements of $A$, and thus $|A| \leq \aleph_0$.

However, I can't tackle **(b)**, even with the hint. I don't really feel how closeness of $B$ is supposed to help us here.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a): Your first part may not be correct. Since you don't apriori know about countability (or uncountability of $A$), you don't know apriori whether  $ \bigcup_{x \in A} G_x$ is a countable union or uncountable union. (Note that countable union of countable sets is necessarily countable).

Therefore, you may proceed as follows for this part:

Let $(G_n)$ be the countable base of $E$. 
Since $A$ does not have any condensation points, if $A$ is empty, we are done. If $A$ is non empty, then let $N=\{k\in \mathbb N: G_{n_k}\cap A \text{ is countable }\}$.
Define $S=\cup_{k\in N} G_{n_k}$.  Let $E\setminus S\ne\emptyset $. Then for any $x$ in $E\setminus S$, if $B(x,\delta)$ is any arbitrary open ball around it then there exists a $G_{n_{k'}}\in (G_n)$ such that $x\in G_{n_{k'}}\subset B(x,\delta)$ and clearly
$n_{k'}\notin N$. It follows that $x$ is a condensation point of $A$, which is a contradiction. Hence $E\setminus S=\emptyset$. It follows that $E=S\implies A$ is countable.

For part $(b)$: First of all, note that $B$ is closed. If not, let $cl(B)-B\ne \emptyset$. 
Let $x\in cl (B)-B$. It follows that $x$ is not a condensation point of $A$ and hence $\exists \delta\gt 0$ such that $B(x,\delta)\cap A$ is countable. 
Since $x$ is a limit point of $B, B(x,\delta)\cap B$ is infinite. Choose $y\in B(x,\delta)\cap B$ such that $y\ne x$ and take $r=\frac 12\min\{d(x,y),\delta -d(x,y)\}$ so that $B(y,r)\subset B(x,\delta) \implies B(y,r)$ contains countably many points of $A$ which is a contradiction as $y$ is a condensation point of $A$.  Therefore, $cl (B)=B\iff B$ is closed. It follows that $B^c$ is open.

Now let $C= \text{set of condensation points of }A\cap B^c$.  
**Claim:** $C$ is empty. 
**Proof:** If not, suppose that $C\ne \emptyset$. Let $p\in C$ be any point in $C$.  For any $\epsilon \gt 0, B(p,\epsilon)\cap (A\cap B^c)\subset B(x,\epsilon)\cap A\implies B(p,\epsilon)\cap (A\cap B^c)$ is countable which is a contradiction as $p$ is a condensation point of $A\cap B^c$. Hence it follows by contradiction that $C=\emptyset\implies A\cap B^c$ is countable.

Comment: The existence of a map $f:P\to Q$ that is one to one but not onto is **not** enough to conclude that $|P|<|Q|$. Otherwise, we could conclude for instance that the cardinality of the set of even numbers is less than the cardinality of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: You are right. I'll make changes. Thanks a lot for your review.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: I have edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Koro Can't we say that $\bigcup_{x \in A} G_x$ is a countable union (regardless of the countability of $A$), as the basis $(G_\lambda)$ is countable? There may be more sets involved in the union, but at most countably many distinct ones.

Comment: @zbrojny120: No because we don't know about cardinality of $A$. Countable union of countable sets is countable however about uncountable union, we can't say. For example: Let $X$ be any subset of $\mathbb N$, then $\cup_{X\subset \mathbb N} X:=$ union of all subsets of $\mathbb N$, is uncountable even though $X$ being a subset of $\mathbb N$ is countable.

Comment: @Koro Are you sure about this? Your counterexample is clearly right, but I'm not sure if it's applicable here. $\bigcup_{x \in A} G_x$ can be also written as $\bigcup_{G \in \{G_x \in (G_\lambda):  x \in A\}} G$, and now we are clearly iterating over a countable set, as $\{G_x \in (G_\lambda):  x \in A\}$ is countable as a subset of $(G_\lambda)$.

Comment: @zbrojny120: I'll think about it. While writing the answer, I always had in my mind the example that I gave above. Can you explicitly write an injective function from A to basis? If yes, then you are right.

Comment: @zbrojny120: Nonetheless, to make the proof more rigorous/complete, you should write an injective function from A to basis in part (a). It is clear from my answer in part (a) that there will certainly exist the injective as $A$ is denumerable.

Comment: @Koro I think I know where my primary mistake lies: what I marked as $G_x$ should have been $G_{i_x}$, where $i_x \in \mathbb{N}$. Would that clarify my proof?

Comment: @zbrojny120: Still that won’t be enough. Reason is that your $G_{i_x}$ may not be disjoint.

Comment: @Koro I also think that there is an easier way to prove that $B$ is closed: Let $x$ be any point of $\complement B$. There exists an open ball $B(x, r)$ which contains at most countably many points of $A$. $B(x, r)$ is a neighborhood of every of its points, so none of them are condensation points of $A$, so $\complement B$ is open. Would that be correct?

Comment: @Koro how would it affect the sum if the sets were not disjoint? It should not increase the countability of the sum, quite the opposite I think.

Comment: @Koro Also, would a surjective function from a countable set to A suffice? For example putting $G_{i_x} \cap A = \{a^{(i_x)}_1, a^{(i_x)}_2,...\}$?

Comment: zbrojny120: About the closed set: yes I think that’s correct. About the disjoint : If G’s were disjoint. One could have mapped each x $\in A$ to any element of G_x and got an injective function immediately proving that cardinality of A is less or equal to that of base G and countablity could follow. With your G’s, you write an injective function from A to G. Then you’ll be able to prove that your A is countable. Can you write an injective from A to G?

Comment: @zbrojny120: How can you be sure that the surjective you mentioned is even well - defined? For example: What if there is some G_n which does not have any image in A?

Comment: @Koro your are right with the possibility of $G_{i_x}$ not having any image in $A$, but then we could just put $a^{(i_x)}_k$ as some arbitrary $a \in A$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ to fix this.

Comment: @Koro also one question regarding your proof of (b): you state that $p \in A$ and it can't be a condensation point of $A$. But $p \in C$ should not imply $p \in A \cap \complement B$, or am I wrong here?

Comment: @zbrojny120: I reiterate that you write an injective function from $A$ to base (G_n). Alternatively, a surjective from ($G_n$) to $A$. In fact, it's a good exercise. And share that function here I also would like to see that.Then you will also have a better clarity as to why directly claiming that $ \bigcup_{x \in A} G_x$ is countable may have problems.

Comment: @zbrojny120: You are right. That was erroneously put there. I wanted to prove that p can't be an element of $A∩B^c$ as hint and leave the other part. My fault that I didn't mention or hint it in the post. Now I have made my post clearer.